# VBA find partial text, copy and paste cell value to specific empty cell

Tags: vba, loops, text, copy, paste

I have a table with a specific column AX29:AX200 i would like to check if contains a certain text. The table is dynamic, so the content will change. What i want to do is create a macro that will check if the cells in that column contains the string "ER". In the column there can be zero or maximum three cells that have "ER" in them. For example it now contains : ERZ2, ERZ3 and ERM3 in the column.

If the cells contain "ER" i want to copy the whole text (f.ex ERZ2) and paste it in a specific cell in the same worksheet (f.ex A30). If there are no data that matches the string, the cell is set as empty.

I have tried to use the following code as of now:

```
Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim Status As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range

Set StatusCol = Worksheets("MOA PF_PLO").Range("AX29:AX200")

For Each Status In StatusCol

 If Worksheets("MOA PF_PLO").Range("A28") = "" Then
      Set PasteCell = Worksheets("MOA PF_PLO").Range("A28")
 Else
      Set PasteCell = Worksheets("MOA PF_PLO").Range("A30")
 
 End If
 
 If Status = "ER" Then Status.Copy PasteCell
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcXuT.png)

But this doesnt work. I can also see that i have less than the maximum number of entries (three) to paste into empty cells (A28 and A30 as of now). Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "doesn't work". Won't you be overwriting by pasting to the same cell?

Comment: Couldnt that be solved by setting them to blank if the criteria isnt met? Or maybe do a clearcontent? As you may see, no expert in this field!

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're trying to do. A screenshot might help.

Comment: Have added a screenshot of the column which contains the data i am interested in. I am only interested in the data in this column, but its not fixed so there could be more or less rows than it is now. The cells contains f.ex "ERZ2" and "ERZ3", what i want to do is to find a macro that searches through all the rows in that column to try and find a partial text i.e. "ER". When it does, i want it to copy that cell (f.ex "ERZ1") and paste it into a specific cell in the same sheet ("A20"). If there are multiple "ER" values, it goes to the next and does the same (copy it and paste in in "A21").